# show error @nrwl/workspace is not installed

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Angular CLI could not be decorated to enable computation caching. Please ensure @nrwl/workspace is installed.
file:///Users/darkseid/Downloads/umn-page-examples-master/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-K2Z44JHH.js:12
import { decode, encode } from "sourcemap-codec";
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'sourcemap-codec' does not provide an export named 'decode'

I am trying all the possibilities and installing all dependencies and modules.

Comment: The problems seems to be in your node version. Try various versions using nvm.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the node version using nvm

```
nvm install 14.15
```

if this version does not work then try

```
nvm install 14.20
```